# React Navigation 'navigation' is missing in props validation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

React Navigation's [introduction page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/) suggests the use of the following destructuring assignment:

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
```

However, when I implemented React Navigation in my App, ESLint is complaining about this line describing these both errors:

> 'navigation' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)
>
> 'navigation.navigation' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)

Even though the app seems to be working as intended, how would it be possible to remove these error lines?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option is to add the `propTypes` prop to the component.

**Example**

```
LoginScreen.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Another option is to disable eslint for that page and rule. More info [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md#rule-options)

> **Rule Options**
>
> This rule can take one argument to ignore some specific props during
>   validation.
>
> ```
> ...
> "react/prop-types": [<enabled>, { ignore: <ignore>, customValidators: <customValidator> }]
> ...
> ```

Comment: Newest version now complains about the object type:
`Eslint: Prop type 'object' is forbidden  react/forbid-prop-types`

Comment: To clarify the rule option mentioned above it would look something like this:
`"react/prop-types": ["error", { "ignore": ["navigation"] }]`

Answer (score 22):

`React.PropTypes` has moved into the `prop-types` package since React v15.5 (see [Typechecking with PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)).

It should be used instead of importing from `react-native` (the package can be added into the project via `npm install --save prop-types` or `yarn add prop-types`).

And the example code complying with "Component should be written as a pure function" rule as follows:

```
// In addition to other imports:
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <View>
    <Button
      title="Login"
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MainScreen')}
    />
  </View>
);

LoginScreen.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.shape({
    navigate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};
```

Comment: This solution definitely looks cleaner.

Answer (score 14):

Solution today (since object Proptype isn't accepted by default anymore):

```
export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.shape({
      navigate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When Project needs navigation to almost all componenets. We can also silence the linting for that specific prop.

By adding the following in the eslint configuration:

```
    "rules": {
     "react/prop-types": ["error", { "ignore": ["navigation"] }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of navigation in ES5 use something like this:

```
LoginScreen.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

in ES6 use this:

```
static PropTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

and

`import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

Comment: It's working but after adding these part of code another warning appear. `Caution: `PropTypes` also has a named export `object`. Check if you meant to write `import {object} from 'prop-types'` instead.` Do you know how to avoid this without throwing exception to `eslint`?